# Problemas para enviar clave por correo a los usuarios

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy creando usuarios automáticamente usando php, necesito que al crearse evnie los datos de la cuenta por correo, si no es posible enviar la clave como seria para mandar un enlace para crear una clave, este es mi codigo:

```
function prueba_user(){

    global $wpdb;

    // Define la información del nuevo usuario
    $new_user_data = array(
        'user_login'    => 'felix123',
        'first_name'    => 'felix',
        'user_pass'     => wp_generate_password(),
        'user_email'    => 'coddinex@gmail.com',
        'nickname'    => 'felix',
        'role'          => 'agent' // Asigna el rol 'agent'
    );

    // Inserta el nuevo usuario
    $agent_user_id = wp_insert_user($new_user_data);

    $user_info = get_userdata($agent_user_id);

    $email_body = "Hola " . $user_info->user_login . ",\n\n";
    $email_body .= "Aquí están los datos de tu cuenta:\n\n";
    $email_body .= "Nombre de usuario: " . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Contraseña: " . $user_info->user_pass . "\n\n";

    wp_mail($user_info->user_email, "Datos de tu cuenta", $email_body);

}
```

Comment: y cual es el error???

Comment: Al intentar mandar la clave llega codificada, entonces no sirve

Comment: Quisiera alguna forma de que le llegue bien o en us defecto enviar un enlace para que creen su clave

Comment: creo que estan implementandolo mal, no se envian contraseñas se envian tokens con un tiempo limite y numero de veces limitado de utilizacion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llega encriptada porque le estas enviando la que ya almacenaste, debes enviarla antes de ser codificada, por ejemplo:

```
function prueba_user(){

    global $wpdb;
    $user_password = wp_generate_password();

    // Define la información del nuevo usuario
    $new_user_data = array(
        'user_login'    => 'felix123',
        'first_name'    => 'felix',
        'user_pass'     => $user_password,
        'user_email'    => 'coddinex@gmail.com',
        'nickname'    => 'felix',
        'role'          => 'agent' // Asigna el rol 'agent'
    );

    // Inserta el nuevo usuario
    $agent_user_id = wp_insert_user($new_user_data);

    $user_info = get_userdata($agent_user_id);

    $email_body = "Hola " . $user_info->user_login . ",\n\n";
    $email_body .= "Aquí están los datos de tu cuenta:\n\n";
    $email_body .= "Nombre de usuario: " . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Contraseña: " . $user_password . "\n\n";

    wp_mail($user_info->user_email, "Datos de tu cuenta", $email_body);

}
```

Comment: Tienes razon, voy a probar esto

Comment: Funciono, gracias